# Quebrando linha array jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou coletando os valores selecionados pelo usuário e jogando em um array. Depois disso, criei um laço para jogar esses valores em uma string para printar na tela. O problema é que estão vindo todos em uma linha só apenas com um espaço entre eles.
Segue código do laço:

```
var descr = "";
for (var i = 0; i < nomes.length; i++) {
    descr = descr + "\n" + nomes[i] + ": " + qtd[i];
}
descr = descr + "\n";
$("#itens").text(descr);
```

Comment: E o que você quer, que o texto pule linha? O \n poderia ser substituído por `<br>`, mas aí depende do que é `#itens` também.

Comment: #itens é um <h2>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Três alternativas:

- como tens e juntando `white-space: pre-wrap;` no CSS
- usando `<br>` como separador e `.html()` em vêz de `.text()`
- usando `<p></p>`

`#1`

```js
var nomes = ['Joao', 'Maria'];
var qtd = [10, 45];
var descr = "";
for (var i = 0; i < nomes.length; i++) {
  descr = descr + "\n" + nomes[i] + ": " + qtd[i];
}
descr = descr + "\n";
$("#itens").text(descr);
```

```css
#itens {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="itens"></div>
```

`#2`

```js
var nomes = ['Joao', 'Maria'];
var qtd = [10, 45];
var descr = "";
for (var i = 0; i < nomes.length; i++) {
  descr = descr + "<br>" + nomes[i] + ": " + qtd[i];
}
descr = descr + "<br>";
$("#itens").html(descr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="itens"></div>
```

`#3`

```js
var nomes = ['Joao', 'Maria'];
var qtd = [10, 45];
var descr = nomes.map(
  (nome, i) => ['<p>', nomes[i], ": ", qtd[i], '</p>'].join('')
);
$("#itens").html(descr);
```

```css
#itens {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="itens"></div>
```

Comment: Utilize a segunda opção. Funcionou! Obrigada

Answer (score 0):

ao invês de concatenar `\n` voce deve concatenar `<br/>` uma vez que o conteudo que voce esta printando eh HTML.

Voce deve tambem ao inves de chamar o metodo `.text(descr)` chamar o metodo `.html(descr)`

```js
var nomes = ['nome 1','nome 2','nome 3','nome 4','nome 5','nome 6'];
var qtd = ['1','2','3','4','5','6'];

var descr = "";
for (var i = 0; i < nomes.length; i++) {
    descr += "<br/>" + nomes[i] + ": " + qtd[i];
}
descr = descr + "<br/>";
$("#itens").html(descr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p id="itens"></p>
```

Comment: Se eu coloco "<br />", ele aparece na tela.
Ex: "Item 1 <br /> Item 2"

Comment: complementei a resposta @lufizi tinha faltado citar o `.html()`